# Context menu icons are invisible in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Icons associated withe file types are invisible in VS 2015-community edition (methods, classes, properties..)
also no icons in the menu bar and the solution bar, when  I hover over an icon it just highlight with a yellow color, no more detail except the popup info box
Any suggested solution, please?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repairing / reinstalling your Visual Studio?

Comment: Also, do you have any other versions of VS installed? If so, do you get that problem there?

Comment: No, I didn't re-install it. and no other version of VS.

Comment: same issue here, anyone yet find a solution?